# Excel VBA generate combinations of cells from 3 columns or more

Tags: vba, excel

I'd like to create keyword combinations in Excel but not all possible permutations (this would create too many combinations)

Here are 3 example columns, I'm listing just 2 values in them here:

```
A:
Two
Three

B:
Red
Blue

C:
Shirts
Jackets
```

And the result would look like this:

```
Two Red Shirts
Two Red Jackets
Two Blue Shirts
Two Blue Jackets
Three Red Shirts
Three Red Jackets
Three Blue Shirts
Three Blue Jackets
```

I don't want words to change their positions, so 3rd word can't become first. Columns can have different numbers of cells. There could be multiple words per cell, and it would be perfect, if it would be easy to change 3 columns combinations to 4 or 5.

Thanks in advance

Comment: -1 because you're obviously just asking us to work for you. If you have a question please ask it. Otherwise this will get closed in no time.

Comment: @AlexandreP.Levasseur I have tried many different ways but I gave up. They all seem to permutate all possible combinations of words, not logically correct...

Answer (score 3):

Something like this might work:

```
Sub test()
  Dim x, y, z, lastRow As Long
  lastRow = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Rows.Count
  For Each x In Range("A1:A" & lastRow)
    For Each y In Range("B1:B" & lastRow)
      For Each z In Range("C1:C" & lastRow)
        Debug.Print x & " " & y & " " & z
      Next z
    Next y
  Next x
End Sub
```

I wrote the output to the Immediate Window, but you can put it anywhere you like.

If you want to add more columns, you'll need to add more loops.  If the cells are empty, it will append nothing(the non-existent cell contents) to the string.

Comment: @JohnyAggro thank you, but I'm not sure how to get it working. I am running the macro but nothing happens. Do I need to select anything for it to work?

Comment: You need to open the Immediate Window. Ctrl + G from the VB editor on a PC.

Comment: @JohnyAggro with 5 lines and 3 columns of text, your solution in Immediate window freezes my Excel

Comment: It works fine in mine.  Are all your cells filled with data?  You may want to find the last row using a different method depending on what your sheet looks like. http://www.mrexcel.com/td0058.html